# vscode integrated terminal throwing bash error - echo: command not found

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, echo

On my Macbook, the integrated terminal in VSCODE which is using bash shell is throwing the error "bash: :echo: command not found" as soon as I open it and on every command that I execute in it.

But I dont see this error in my iterm or Terminal though. They both work fine. I am getting this error only in VSCode integrated terminal

It was not happening previously. I am not sure what got changed recently.

I checked if the same issue is happening in iterm and Terminal also or not. But it doesn't happen in them.

Checked the .bash_profile and .bashrc files. But they seem to be fine.

Only place I can find echo command in my bash_profile:

```
if [ $ITERM_SESSION_ID ]; then
  export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033];${PWD##*/}\007";':"$PROMPT_COMMAND";
fi
```

.bashrc doesn't contain any echo commands

Please let me know why this error is coming in vscode integrated terminal only and how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033];${PWD##*/}\007";':"$PROMPT_COMMAND";
```

Try this one:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033];${PWD##*/}\007"';
```